# Form with two submit button doesn't function properly

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am developing a web application and I have designed a form in my jsp page.
I have some text fields and two submit buttons "send" and "search".I want my form to perform two different action when these buttons are pressed.But my action on click of search button is same as click of send button please help me on this.
Below is part of my code.

```html
<form name="Field_Details" action="ServletApp" method="get">
  <fieldset style="float: center; width:920px; height: 75px;background-color:ivory; border-color:black;">
    <font size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MachId :</font> 
    <input type="text" name="Text2" maxlength="15" style="height:15px; width:100px; border-color:black"><font size="2"></font>
    <font size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;From Date(dd/mm/yy) :</font> 
    <input type="text" name="Text3" maxlength="8" style="height:15px; width:100px; border-color:black"><font size="2"></font>
    <font size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To Date(dd/mm/yy) :</font> 
    <input type="text" name="Text4" maxlength="8" style="height:15px; width:100px; border-color:black"><font size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" style="height:30px; width:80px; formaction="FirstServlet"/><br><br>
    <font size = "2">Output Field :</font> <input type="text" name="Text1" maxlength="50"  style="height:15px; width:100px; border-color:black"><font size = "2"></font>
    <input type= "submit" value="Send" style="height:30px; width:80px; margin-left:15px">
```

Comment: How is this related to Javascript? (And for purposes of this question couldn't you have shown a simplified form rather than a wall of non-breaking spaces and font tags?)

Comment: I agree but i just copied the part from my code. will surely keep this in mind when i ask next time

Comment: I don't see a problem with the code. Clicking on `Send` should invoke `ServletApp`, clicking on `Search` should invoke `FirstServlet`.

Comment: why don't you use <label> tag instred of <font> and to avoid &nbsp; you can give padding-left to the same.

Comment: The font tag has been deprecated/obsolete for ages.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in the first submit button, you're missing the quotes at the end of the `style` attribute. So `formaction` is being seen as part of the `style`, not a separate attribute.

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" style="height:30px; width:80px;" formaction="FirstServlet"/><br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things wrong here. I'm not saying to make you feel bad, just to help.

- In HTML, attributes should never have spaces around the equal signs. Not sure if some browsers are forgiving you for this and letting it work, but it's not standard and who knows, may be the cause of some of the issues

  - Never use the `<font>` element as it is obsolete https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font Strive to use CSS instead
  - You should almost never need the `&nbsp;` entity, strive to use CSS instead
  - Until you get more experienced, strive to never use inline styles (that's the style attribute in your HTML). Strive to use external CSS instead
  - You should use  elements instead of `<input type="submit">` as it is more semantic

Honestly, none of these things are necessarily the reason why the code is not working, but the way you have this written makes it pretty difficult for others to look at and evaluate what's going on to help you

Comment: And <button>s are not necessarily more semantic than <input>s. Other than that, your points are good ideas, but you should explain _why_ they are good ideas, not just these hit-and-run "this is bad" remarks. And you never mention the OP's _real_ errors (`float: center` etc).

Answer (score 0):

This below code worked fine for me

```
<form name = "Field_Details" action="ServletApp" method= "get">
    <fieldset style="float: center; width:920px; height: 75px;background-color:ivory; border-color:black;">
    <font size = "2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MachId :</font> <input type="text" name="Text2" maxlength="15"  style="height:15px; width:100px; border-color:black"><font size = "2"></font>
    <font size = "2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;From Date(dd/mm/yy) :</font> <input type="text" name="Text3" maxlength="8"  style="height:15px; width:100px; border-color:black"><font size = "2"></font>
    <font size = "2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To Date(dd/mm/yy) :</font> <input type="text" name="Text4" maxlength="8"  style="height:15px; width:100px; border-color:black"><font size = "2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" style="height:30px; width:80px;" onclick='this.form.action="FirstServlet";'/><br><br>
    <font size = "2">Output Field :</font> <input type="text" name="Text1" maxlength="50"  style="height:15px; width:100px; border-color:black"><font size = "2"></font>
    <input type= "submit" value="Send"  style="height:30px; width:80px; margin-left:15px";/>
```

you can just write this for submit button.I have used this only for one submit button because I wanted my second submit buttons action same as the form action.

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" style="height:30px; width:80px;"   onclick='this.form.action="FirstServlet";'/><br><br>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<form name = "Field_Details" action = "ServletApp" method= "get">
<fieldset style="float: center; width:920px; height: 75px;background-color:ivory; border-color:black;">
<font size = "2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MachId :</font> <input type="text" name="Text2" maxlength="15"  style="height:15px; width:100px; border-color:black"><font size = "2"></font>
<font size = "2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;From Date(dd/mm/yy) :</font> <input type="text" name="Text3" maxlength="8"  style="height:15px; width:100px; border-color:black"><font size = "2"></font>
<font size = "2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To Date(dd/mm/yy) :</font> <input type="text" name="Text4" maxlength="8"  style="height:15px; width:100px; border-color:black"><font size = "2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
<input type= "submit" value="Search" onclick="submitForm('FirstServlet');" style="height:30px; width:80px; formaction="FirstServlet"/><br><br>
<font size = "2">Output Field :</font> <input type="text" name="Text1" maxlength="50"  style="height:15px; width:100px; border-color:black"><font size = "2"></font>
<input type= "submit" value="Send" onclick="submitForm('ServletApp');" style="height:30px; width:80px; margin-left:15px">
```

Comment: Can you explain what you changed to fix the problem?

Comment: Added onclick attributes to the two submit buttons to submit form using javascript. Please observe.

Comment: Put the explanation in the answer, not a comment. And explain why it was necessary.

Comment: You also need to provide the definition of `submitForm`.